Alexa Simulator testing unresponsive
I am trying to write a custom alexa skill but after the first message it doesn't work for the second message.
Simulator snippet
I tried using the
reprompt 

and the
should_end_session


flags, but it didn't work. I am attaching a couple of handler classes below:
class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        speak_output = "Welcome to my skill. How can I help you today?"
        reprompt_text = "You can ask me to do something. How can I assist you?"

        return handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).reprompt(reprompt_text).set_should_end_session(False).response

class ProgressRequestHandler((AbstractRequestHandler)):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("progress")(handler_input)
    def handlle(self,handler_input):
        speak_output = "He is working on the hackathon project"
        return(
            handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).response)

Please help me with this.

I contacted the Alexa support about this same issue (though with nodeJS) - they seem to be investigating it.

@lukeschwoebel please let me know if they respond

I had the same issue  and asked the Amazon support about it, it seemed to have been an issue in the developer console that is said to be fixed now.
Just created a new skill from scratch (nodeJS) with a proper reprompt and withShouldEndSession(false) for good measure, and now I get a properly kept open session again.
Correction: I just created a new new skill, even with APL enabled which should definitely keep the session open, and there I now still get the direct session-ended-requests. Gonna have to re-open the Amazon ticket :-/
